# How to know process id of host process that executes my executable in windows service?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have C# windows service application `myapp.exe` that I have installed as windows service. The process list of Task Manager shows `svchost.exe` as process for all windows services that are running. I want to find which out of all of these `svchost.exe` is running my executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the PID of a Windows service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23084720/get-the-pid-of-a-windows-service)

Comment: Its probably wrong question as it shows myapp.exe as process in task manager. sorry! I will be deleting the question in sometime.

Comment: The svchost.exe is only used by Microsoft's services.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a different name to your process using **Project installer Class** Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5216235/2976484) to see how you could do that.

Once this is done you could get the Process ID for your application using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698222/2976484)